Laravel excel returns empty when i use a custom filter
Am working on this laravel excel but I received an empty result. So just to emphazise In my controller I need to filter the model before passing it in the ScanExport but am receiving an empty output.
this is my controller
public function export(Request $request)
{
    $user = $request->user();
    $user_id = $user->id;
    $user_code = $user->code;

    $result = Scan::where([
            ['user_id', $user_id],
            ['code', $user_code]
        ])
        ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
        ->get();
    
    $data = collect(json_decode($result, true));
                  
    $scans = $data->groupBy(function ($item) {
            return $item['barcode'] . '_' . $item['location'];
        })
        ->map(function ($group) {
            return [
                'id' => $group->first()['id'],
                'barcode' => $group->first()['barcode'],
                'description' => $group->first()['description'],
                'qty' => $group->sum('qty'),
                'location' => $group->first()['location'],
            ];
        })
        ->values()
        ->each(function ($item, $index) {
            $item['id'] = $index + 1;
        });
    
    return Excel::download(new ScansExport($scans), 'Scan.xlsx');
}

this is my ScanExport file
class ScansExport implements FromCollection, WithHeadings, ShouldAutoSize
{
    private $scans;
    
    public function __construct($scans)
    {
        $this->scans = $scans;
    }
    
    public function collection()
    {
        return $this->scans;
    }
        
    public function headings():array
    {
        return [
            'code',
            'location',
            'barcode',
            'description',
            'qty',
        ];
    }
}

hopefully someone can point out what i am missing here.  thanks

That json_decode line doesn't seem right. I don't think you need it.
The $user_* variables seem superfluous and since you can chain collection methods right away, you could do it straight away
public function export(Request $request)
{
    $scans = Scan::query()
        ->where('user_id', $request->user()->id)
        ->where('code', $request->user()->code)
        ->orderByDesc('id')
        ->get()
        ->groupBy(fn (Scan $scan): string => "{$scan->barcode}_{$scan->location}")
        ->map(fn ($group): array => [
            'id' => $group->first()['id'],
            'barcode' => $group->first()['barcode'],
            'description' => $group->first()['description'],
            'qty' => $group->sum('qty'),
            'location' => $group->first()['location'],
        ])
        ->values()
        ->each(function (&$item, $index) {
            $item['id'] = $index + 1;
        });
    
    return Excel::download(new ScansExport($scans), 'Scan.xlsx');
}

As a sidenote, does making the query not work?
$scans = Scan::query()
    ->where('user_id', $request->user()->id)
    ->where('code', $request->user()->code)
    ->groupBy('barcode', 'location')
    ->orderByDesc('id')
    ->get()

